# .gitignore file is not ignoring a certain file

Tags: git, gitignore

This is my .gitignore page

```
.DS_Store
node_modules
/dist


# local env files
.env.local
.env.*.local

# Log files
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
pnpm-debug.log*

# Editor directories and files
.idea
.vscode
*.suo
*.ntvs*
*.njsproj
*.sln
*.sw?

#dbconnector
dbconnector.js
```

And it isn't ignoring the dbconnector.js file who is on that specific location

I already tryed this three lines as replacement for `dbconnector.js` but it doesn't worked

```
server/dbconnector.js
./server/dbconnector.js
**/dbconnector.js
```

Comment: Was the file added to VCS before it was marked as ignored through the gitignore?

Comment: Is the file untracked? Only untracked files can be ignored.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question but I'm new to git.
How can i know if i added the file to VCS or not?

Comment: Does the file show under "Changes not staged for commit" or "Changes to be committed" in the output of `git status`; or is it listed below "Untracked files"? If the former, it is already tracked (added with `git add` in an earlier commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch for spurious characters in and around the filename in `.gitignore`. Do not forget to add newline after the name.

If the file is already tracked, use `git rm --cached server/dbconnector.js` (precise pathname for each file).
(See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/22357050) and around there.)

I suppose other files are well git-ignored, so there is no need for a test with a new file, like `echo hello >> hello; echo hello >> .gitignore; git status`. Thought it does not hurt to take the test.

Comment: (Which one worked for you ?)

Comment: I used this command `git rm --cached server/dbconnector.js` and then when the file became untracked the .gitignore ignorde it.

I can´t vote yet, i need 2 more repotation...